# Created PWA - homepage icon for Chrome works, but not Firefox

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I've created a PWA, and mobile Chrome allows add to homescreen, with the proper icon. Firefox also allows install to homescreen, but no icon?

My index.html contains:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
```

My manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
  "short_name": "coolapp",
  "name": "coolapp",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-36-36.png",
      "sizes": "36x36",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-48-48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-72-72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-96-96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-128-128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-144-144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-192-192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/splash-128-128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

So the icon was working for both, until I added "beforeinstallprompt" handling, and now the icon only installs for Chrome, not Firefox. Am I also correct that "beforeinstallprompt" never calls on FF, only Chrome? On FF, a Homescreen icon with a + appears in the browser, for the user to install to homescreen - but it installs less like an app than Chrome (it's more like just a shortcut, whereas Chrome goes through a whole process)

Answer (score 3):

'beforeinstallprompt' is only available in Chrome, yes.

And while PWA's work on Android through Firefox and Opera, only Chrome has proper standalone support. PWA's installed through Firefox or Opera will just show up as shortcuts on your homescreen, like you said. It still works as a PWA, however, but it looks off because it's not in the app drawer.